# Checkbox field in TreeView with PySide

Tags: qt4, pyside, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

I'm looking for some way of rendering a boolean value in a QTreeView as a checkbox rather than a dropdown (as seems to be the default). The specific limitation I have is that I do not wish to subclass QTreeView since this would involve replacing a widget in the generated .py file (from the .ui file).

PySide: v1.2.1
QtCore: v4.8.5
Python: 2.7